# Quickest shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I want to do a shortest path algorithm. My direct and not acyclic graph contains only positive numbers. I have to do the scan for all pairs of nodes in complete depth in python. My graph is big (100x100x100 (with time-steps) and I have to do it in a time efficient way. I tried to do it with Dijkstra but it was far too slow. I also tried a Floyd-Warshall algorithm but I think that this algorithm doesn't scan the graph in complete depth (?). I would be thankful for other algorithms and additional advices.

Comment: Is your graph acyclic ?

Comment: No, it is not acyclic.

Comment: You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953197/which-is-the-best-algorithmtime-complexity-to-find-the-shortest-path#:~:text=Single%2Dsource%20shortest%20path%20is,typically%20faster%20on%20dense%20graphs.) for an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest path between two specific nodes? or between one specific node and all other nodes? or between all pairs of nodes?

Comment: Between all pairs of nodes.

Comment: Then, the most efficient is to run a Dijkstra algorithm for each node. If you really want the shortest paths between all pairs, there is not much more you can do. Your options are: 1) not computing the shortest paths between all pairs, for example, for each node, you only compute the shortest paths to the 100 closest nodes, 2) use a better implementation, in Cython or C++, you might already gain a factor 10, but it might not be sufficient

Comment: Thank you. I will try it!

Comment: It might be outdated, but for efficient C++ implementations of shortest path algorithms for road networks (ie. very sparse graphs) you can read this "old" post: http://stegua.github.io/blog/2012/09/19/dijkstra/

Comment: If the graph is very dense (i.e. the number of edges is close to the number of vertices squared) Floyd-Warshall would be faster than Dijkstra. I don't understand what you mean by "scan the graph in complete depth"?

Comment: Also, could you give a bit more information about the structure of your graph? Do you have some information related to the time-steps, for instance? For example, if you can assume that the distance between two nodes can never be more than their distance in time, more clever algorithms than Dijkstra or Floyd-Warshall could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are promising options:

1. **floyd-warshall** algorithm for dense graphs
2. **johnson** algorithm for sparse graphs
3. (not sure if it's worth to try and it will work well) **dijkstra** algorithm parallelized for each vertex

Regarding your question, a correct floyd-warshall implementation scans all the pairs.